# Timezone helper in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, timezone, cakephp-2.1, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to populate the select box with countries' timezones. I have seen examples and answers here, but nothing works out for me. I am working on Cakephp 2.3.

My `timeZone` helper class is in this directory 
**App/View/Helper/TimeZoneHelper.php**.

**Here is my controller:**

```
   class TimeZoneController extends AppController{

    public function index(){
    $helpers = array('TimeZoneHelper');


  }

 }
```

**my view**

```
  <?php

  echo $timezone->select('timezone');
  ?>
```

It isn't working, and I don't know how it works because I have never used this functionality before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with cake2.x. But you are using 1.x syntax.
The correct syntax for 2.x is:

```
echo $this->Timezone->select('timezone');
```

(instead of $timezone-select)

Its also in the documentation by the way:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-helpers

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add helper in action you need to use following code

```
class TimeZoneController extends AppController{
    public function index(){
     $this->helpers[] = 'TimeZoneHelper';
    }
}
```

If you want the helper to available to all the action

```
class TimeZoneController extends AppController{
    public $helpers = array('TimeZoneHelper');
    public function index(){
    }
}
```

If you want the helper to be available to all controllers then you need to add it to /app/Controller/AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller{
    public $helpers = array('TimeZoneHelper');
}
```